# How to get the selected section in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a HistoryTableViewController with 2 sections hooked up to a detail view controller. I want to be able to display the text and subtitle text from the HistoryTableViewController in the details view, but I want to make sure that it detects the right section. I know somewhere along the line I'll have this:

```
if (section == 0)
{
labelCellNum.text = Whatever was the main text in the selected table view cell
labelDueDate.text = Whatever was in the subtitle text in the selected table view cell
}

 else if (section == 1)
{
labelCellNum.text = Whatever was the main text in the selected table view cell
labelDueDate.text = Whatever was in the subtitle text in the selected table view cell
}
```

Since I'm displaying this on a details view controller, I don't know how to get the section from the TableViewController I'm getting displayed from. I pretty much need to know how to get the section, and the main text + subtitle text.

OK Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. This code is going in my ViewDidLoad of my DetailsViewController. NOT in my tableviewcontroller.

Here is the HistoryTableviewController code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
{
 // HistoryDetailsViewController *HDV = [self.storyboard      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryDetails"];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:HDV animated:YES];
NSLog(@"index path section--%i",[indexPath section]);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Push" sender:indexPath];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {

    HistoryDetailsViewController *detailVC=(HistoryDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;


    detailVC.labelCellNum.text = @"Cell test";
    detailVC.labelDueDate.text = @"Date Test";
}
}
```

And below is the code of my detailsViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{



labelCellNum.text = @"This isnt even getting called.";

}
```

Comment: Are you changing the content of the detail viewcontroller when you select some item on the table view controller?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to make my labels in my details view controller equal whatever is the cell's title and subtitle text.

Comment: from where you are calling prepareforsegue in detailviewcontroller?please check this link for helping your self with storyboard programming. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 2):

check this , its simple

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"index path section--%i",[indexPath section]);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Push" sender:indexPath];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {

    DetailViewController *detailVC=(DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.title=@"value to pass";
}
}
```

Comment: Can I use this method in my DetailsViewController? Because this code looks like it should go in my TableViewController and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you need to pass some data to you detail view controller from table view controller, & are you using storyboard?

Comment: I'm able to NSLog the correct section number, but the labels stay the same when I do detailVC.labelCellNum.text = @"Test"

Comment: i need to check code for your controller, tabviewcontroller & detailviewcontroller. im not sure how you are doing this . paste codes of your both controller

Answer (score 1):

There you go!

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Selected item infos
    //
    int section = indexPath.section;
    int row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"section: %d / row: %d", section, row);
}
```

Comment: This method is going in my DetailsViewController right? Because when i put it there it doesn't even get called.

Comment: You need to assign your table view delegate to be `DetailsViewController` in your `viewDidLoad`. Usually by doing `self.tableView.delegate = self` Or directly via the storyboard properties of the table view using drag and drop. There is a storyboard tutorial http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html

Comment: I've already set the tableview.delegate = self in the HistoryTableViewController

Comment: Where are you assigning the delegate? Can you check if `tableview` is not `nil` right before setting the `delegate`?

Comment: In my viewDidLoad of my HistoryTableViewController I have myTableView.delegate = self; and I checked if it was nil and it is not.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have a segue from the HistoryVC to the details VC.  So you can pass the data across to the details VC in the prepareForSegue method in the HistoryVC.  In the code fragment below, I am passing the cell title over into the new VC to set it's title.  You could set other properties in the target VC, to suit your needs.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
           // get selected row's cell
           //
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           // set desitination VC title
           //
           UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
           vc.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: This method isn't getting called for me. even though i  added the if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Push"])

Comment: Not sure why this answer got dinged. It seems to match the requirement.  The data needs to be pushed across the segue to the details VC, not pulled across from within the details VC. Also, there is no need to code the segue when you can do it via the storyboard.